# Google translation links not working consistently from android webview

Tags: android, webview, google-translate

I want to send URL's to Google translate and have the translated result display in my webview i.e. I have a button that says "translate current page"

The generated link works fine on desktop and other browsers but **inconsistently** in my android webview.

An example of a URL that won't translate on my webview but does on my application installed on another device: https://www.komplett.fi

Here are a couple of attempts to generate the URL that work just fine in other browsers but work inconsistently in android webview:

http://translate.google.com/m?hl=en&sl=auto&tl=en&ie=UTF-8&prev=_m&q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.komplett.fi%2F

https://translate.google.com/translate?js=n&sl=auto&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.komplett.fi%2F

When it doesn't work I get the error "400. That's an error. Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request" on the Google translate site.

Looking at the URL again after it's finished redirected you end up with something like...

http://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_p?hl=en&ie=UTF8&prev=_m&sl=auto&tl=en&u=https://www.komplett.fi/&depth=1&rurl=translate.google.com&nv=1&sp=nmt4&xid=17259,1500004,15700022,15700122,15700124,15700149,15700186,15700190,15700201&usg=ALkJrhgAAAAAW_g7pjc2_2z1Shv4_-AkDhrzRQ_xSJFb

Which again works consistently outside of webviews but inconsistently inside them.

I've tried various different links and combinations of encoding and have no idea why this doesn't consistently work. I shouldn't need to use an API if I'm just sending the user to the Google translate site should I? Please help, thanks

Comment: I'm having this same exact issue.`https://translate.google.com/translate?` link works ok in desktop browsers (IE, Chrome, Firefox) but does not work in Chrome for mobile. In my case, the website is displayed in the original language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved this problem, or at least I haven't seen it since I did this change. Previously when I wanted to translate a new page I was opening it in a new tab with a new webview but since changing the logic to reload the current page/webview instead I haven't encountered any translation problems.